# p:selectOneMenu formulario no toma valor de item seleccionado

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo un formulario en JSF en el cual pido se seleccione una opción de un `p:selectOneMenu` que lista nombres de reuniones `String` pero quiero guardar el objeto como tal mapeado: Reunión.

Realicé el `FacesCOnverter` necesario para que me traiga el valor de la base de datos y comprobé que lo realiza bien pero a la hora de dar clic en enviar en el formulario no me realiza la acción del `bean` contenida en el botón `p:commandButton`.

```
<h:form>
        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true"/>
        <br /><br />
    <table>          
        <tr>
            <td width="150px">Seleccione Reunion: </td>
            <td>  
                <p:selectOneMenu id="nombreEvento"  panelStyle="width: 1080px" value="#{registrarDelegadoReunion.reunionSelected}" 
                                 converter="reunionConverter" converterMessage="Fallo la conversion de reunion">                         
                    <f:selectItems value="#{registrarDelegadoReunion.lisReuniones}" var="reunion1"  itemLabel="#{reunion1.nombre}" 
                                   itemValue="#{reunion1}" />                                           
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="150px">
                <p:commandButton value="Registrar"  action="#{registrarDelegadoReunion.registrarDelegadoReunion()}" /> 
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </h:form>
```

y este es el `bean` de `registrarDelegadoReunion` y método `registrarDelegadoReunion()`:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "registrarDelegadoReunion")
//@Named(value= "registrarDelegadoReunion")
@SessionScoped
@Stateless
public class registrarDelegadoReunion implements Serializable
{

    private Reunion reunionSelected;    
public String registrarDelegadoReunion()
    {
       //Session sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();      
       //Transaction transaccion=sesion.beginTransaction();
       String urlDestino="msgError";
       System.out.println("Entro en registrarDelegadoReunion");
         return urlDestino;
    }
```

Se supone que debe tomar el formulario y sin importar re-enviarme a la pagina llamada msgError

-------------he añadido esto para que de pronto me guieis::

Hola a todos... He verificado y el problema resulta en el converter (no se por qué a lo mejor alguno me pueda explicar) ::: cuando hago la búsqueda en la base de datos para traer el pojo (objeto de la base de datos llamado reunión) no es posible abstraerlo completamente, a lo mejor porque este tiene referencias a otra tabla u objeto llamado entidad que es la que organiza la reunión. Os muestro el pojo Reunion:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reunion"
    ,schema="ufps"
)
public class Reunion  implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="id_reunion", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public short getIdReunion() {
        return this.idReunion;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_entidad")
    public Entidad getEntidad() {
        return this.entidad;
    }
}
```

y este mi FacesConverter:

```
@FacesConverter("reunionConverter")
public class ReunionConverter implements Converter 
{    

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) 
    {
        Reunion pe=null;
        Session sesion=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();      
        Transaction transaccion=sesion.beginTransaction();
        //Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) 
        {       

            try 
            {
                String consulta="select s from Reunion s where s.idReunion="+value;
                       // +value;

                System.out.println("consulta: "+consulta);
                pe= (Reunion) sesion.createQuery(consulta).uniqueResult();

                if(pe==null)
                {System.out.println("pe es nulo en Reunionconverter: ");}
                else
                {System.out.println("Valor de PE en Reunionconverter: "+pe.getNombre());}

            } catch(NumberFormatException e) 
            {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {                
                System.out.println("Error en la consulta::: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            finally 
            {
                transaccion.commit();
                System.out.println("cerro sesion en reunionCOnverter");
                sesion.close();
            }
        }          

        return pe;

        //return null;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) 
    {
        if(object != null) 
        {
            //SubseriePK op=(SubseriePK) object;
            System.out.println("Objeto en converter reunion: "+ String.valueOf(((Reunion) object).getIdReunion()));

            return String.valueOf(((Reunion) object).getIdReunion());            
        }           
    }
```

como os decia, no me permite abstraer el objeto reunion, ya que hago la prueba con otras tablas (objetos) que no tienen foraneas y ahi si me las trae y ejecuta el bean.

Comment: si requieren el facesConverter solo os digo que el funciona normal pues me trae el objeto Reunion pero no lo quiere tomar el formulario...

Comment: Dices que es como si no llamara al método `registrarDelegadoReunion`?

Comment: No sé si tiene que ver con el error pero `@Stateless` es una anotación para EJBs no para beans de JSF. Remuévela y prueba nuevamente. Indica los problemas y algún stacktrace que aparezca en tu consola de aplicación.

Comment: Además, considera que `<p:commandButton>` utiliza ajax, por lo que tu respuesta en `String` no hará un forward como lo esperas. Debes agregarle el atributo `ajax=false` si quieres dicho comportamiento o ejecutar un callback que permita navegar/redirigir a la siguiente vista.

Comment: Hola a todos... He verificado y el problema resulta en el converter (no se por que a lo mejor alguno me pueda explicar) ::: cuando hago la busqueda en la bd para traer el pojo (objeto de la base de datos llamado reunion) a lo mejor como este tiene referencias a otras tablas y en el pojo tiene: ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_entidad")
    public Entidad getEntidad() {
        return this.entidad;
    } ////////// no me permite abstraer el objeto reunion, ya que hago la prueba con otras tablas (objetos) que no tienen foraneas y ahi si me las trae y ejecuta el bean.

Comment: @LumarSanchez ¿de casualidad estás inyectando en tu converter el `DAO` o `Servicio` de `Reunion`? Es decir, ¿estás usando `@Inject`? Si es así he allí el problema. Un converter (anotado con `@FacesConverter`) no puede tener dependencias inyectadas por medio de `CDI`. En ese caso, deberías remover `@FacesConverter` y añadir `@Named`. Así mismo, en el facelets colocar: `coverter="#{ReunionConverter}"`. 

Además, siempre que estás en desarrollo y trabajas con AJAX, siempre añade `<h:message for=... />` o `<h:messages />` para que en caso de error de validación, converter, etc., lo veas.

Comment: Hola @MitsuGami, no, no utilizo '@Inject'. como os comento solo me pasa en este caso particular que tiene foraneas porque hago la prueba con un pojo normal y si realiza el action del p:commandButton... es mas añadi al codigo ariba el contenido del faces converter

Comment: Pero necesitamos información, qué tipo de error/excepción, muestra el rastreo de pila, ¿colocaste el `<h:messages />`?

Comment: @MitsuGami no es que no bota error... mire coloque un output en consola para que vea que sale del converter:Información:   consulta: select s from Reunion s where s.idReunion=55
Información:   Hibernate: select reunion0_.id_reunion as id_reuni1_3_, reunion0_.id_entidad as id_entid2_3_, reunion0_.id_lugar as id_lugar3_3_, reunion0_.nombre as nombre4_3_, reunion0_.fecha as fecha5_3_ from ufps.reunion reunion0_ where reunion0_.id_reunion=55
Información:   Valor de PE en Reunionconverter: ATENCION Y ASISTENCIA DE EDUCACION EN EMERGENCIA - VICTIMAS
Información:   cerro sesion en reunionCOnverter

Comment: Osea, ¿me dices que no hay error y aun así el método del bean no se llama? Coloca el tag `<h:messages />` para ver si algo se está escapando.

Comment: @MitsuGami no genera ningun mensaje.. solo hace el faceConverter, y vuelve y carga pagina (por asi decirlo)... lo quito y funciona o lo hago con otro pojo y tambien funca

Answer (score 1):

hace tiempo me sucedio el mismo error y recuerdo que lo solucioné adicionando la etiqueta

```
p:ajax event="change" update="@this"/>
```

para mi caso

```
    p:selectOneMenu filter="true" 
        id="tipoAlergeno" value="#{tuController.variableCon_Getters_Setters}"
        required="true">
        f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemValue="0"/>
        f:selectItems value="#{tuControllerEntity.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
            var="Item"
            itemValue="#{Item}"
            itemLabel="#{tipoAlergenoItem.atributo}"/>
        p:ajax event="change" update="@this" />
    /p:selectOneMenu>
```

A mi parecer se soluciona con la etiqueta, ya que actualiza el bloque dentro de **p:selectOneMenu**, por lo cual se renderizará y modificara la variable del controlador.

Comment: exelente me sirvio bastante muchas gracias.